# What's Ruby idiom use global data in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, eventmachine

I have a `Ruby on Rails` application which need to send HTTP request to a remote server frequently. And I want to keep those (there're more than one clients) `em-http-client` globally instead of creating one client every time. But I'm not very clear about WHERE should I store that client array in?
For example, store in the session? Or, ROR has prepared something like a out-of-box singleton pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `ruby` itself has `singleton` pattern ability. Check out the [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html).

So you need in-process storage which are persistent between request.

In `RubyOnRails` you can use following options:

- **global** variables (bad idea, i don't know why)
- **class**  variables (bad idea because they are shared through entire inheritance tree)
- **instance** variable of `metaclass`
- **in-thread** storage (`Thread.current[:whatever]`)
- *somewhere else where I've forgotten*

And good idea is initialize it in `config/initializers/your_initializer.rb`.

I prefer third option.

Here is naive implementation what you're looking for.

```
  class EMClient

    class << self
      attr_accessor :pool
    end
    @pool = []

  end
```

Comment: But everyone told me that class variable is a bad smell in ruby code. Why that?

Comment: @harryz, there is misunderstanding between each other. I've updated answer.